# How to create multiple guest session on ubuntu or others linux distros?

Tags: linux, session, docker, virtual, remote-access

i want to create an application that allow many people can execute command line to a server in same time. And each one have a "virtual 
session" (i don't know how to call that exactly), that allow him create file, folder, ... and will destroy when he disconnect.
So, i really want to know how to create multiple guest session on Ubuntu or others linux distros ? Or use other technology like docker, VMware,...
Thanks for your help.
Ps: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Look for some tutorials about docker. Maybe also a jailroot as offered by rsh might be of interest ("reduced shell").

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i think if i just use jailroot, rsh , i will add many temporary users and delete them after they disconnect.
I also see docker compose : https://docs.docker.com/compose/ . It seem very interesting.
Do you have any comment about that ?

Comment: About rsh: certainly you don't want to create a local account for all users, but that is not required here. GNU/Linux typically uses PAM for authentication tasks, that gives you unlimited freedom here: it allows to authenticate against any thinkable authority instead of local accounts: LDAP, mysql, or even a "dummy" authority granting access. That way you can define a "pseudo" or "virtual" account for all those users, including some fixed jailrooted home directory and login shell (rsh) they all share. I cannot contribute anything about that composer think for docker, sorry.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. But if i use only a "pseudo" account then users must share the same jailrooted folder. So, they can see, edit or delete other's file and I don't want that to happen. Maybe we need to think another way. Have a nice day, bro.

Comment: You still did not think about PAM, apparently. Nothing speaks against setting up a separate jailroot environment to your liking in the account step. As said before: you can do whatever you like, that is the power of the idea. So for example keep a "skeleton" environment you simply fork for each login and use it as jailrooted home location. Setup whatever file hierarchy you need in there and whatever environment variables you require.

Comment: I had read some document on internet about PAM and i think "linux polyinstantiation" is what i need. I will read more about it. Thank you so much @arkascha .